# make width of element by character size

Tags: html, css

I want to make the width of div equal 10 character size

let say that single character takes `2px` so I want the width equals to `20px` even if the text was only 4 characters

```
<div class="row"> 
     <div class="key">City</div> 
     <div class="value"><div class="XYZ">AL-NAJAF</div>
</div> 
<div class="row"> 
     <div class="key">City</div> 
     <div class="value"><div class="XYZ">NEW BAGHDAD</div>
</div>
```

what I'm looking for is something like this :

```
.XYZ {
    width : 10character;
}
```

Comment: Width of an *I* or *X* character?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sorry didn't get you

Comment: He means that not all characters are the same width. The only way to calculate the width of 10 characters is if you use a monospace font such as Courier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For monospaced fonts you could use `width: calc(10 * 6px);`